# SQL Select all except

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select all records from the trips table except the trips done by vehicle1 for contract1. Something like:

```
   SELECT * FROM trips
   WHERE vehicle != 'vehicle1'
   WHILE contract = 'contract1'
```

Comment: This is indeed a very basic query i would suggest to go through Sql queries tutorial - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
SELECT * FROM trips
WHERE vehicle <> 'vehicle1'
OR   contract <> 'contract1'
```

or this

```
SELECT * FROM trips
WHERE NOT (vehicle = 'vehicle1' AND contract = 'contract1')
```

Comment: Went with your second suggestion. Worked 100%

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean operators (AND)   - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

for example: where vehicle!='vehicle1' and contract = 'contract1'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you need is just the `or` logical operator to check that at least one of these conditions doesn't happen on the same row:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   trips
WHERE  vehicle != 'vehicle1' OR contract != 'contract1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding but couldn't you do something like

SELECT * FROM trips WHERE NOT (vehicle = 'vehicle1' AND contract = 'contract1')